# With Shiro.ini , How I can block a page of a logged users? (only NOT logged user can see a page)

Tags: java, security, ini, shiro

I have to "block" login.xhtml page to logged users , they have to logout to use login.xhtml page.

I put anon or authc on urls config and after login still can go to login.xhtml.

```
[main]
...
...
authc=org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter
authc.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
[urls]
/javax.faces.resource/** = anon
/login.xhtml=anon
/admin/** = authc
/logout = logout
/** = anon
```

I only use shiro.ini file to config
(it should not leave me until logout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Create a new class filter

```
public class OnlyNotAutenticated extends  AccessControlFilter{

String welcomeurl="";

@Override
protected boolean isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, Object mappedValue) throws Exception {
     Subject subject = getSubject(request, response);
     return !subject.isAuthenticated(); // THE POINT

}

@Override
protected boolean onAccessDenied(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    WebUtils.issueRedirect(request, response, welcomeurl);
    return false;//What to do if try to go to login -> go welcome page of auth ursers
}

public String getWelcomeurl() {
    return welcomeurl;
}

public void setWelcomeurl(String welcomeurl) {
    this.welcomeurl = welcomeurl;
}
```

}

in Shiro.ini:

```
[main]
...
onlynot=edu.eci.cvds.security.OnlyNotAutenticated ; path of you filter
onlynot.welcomeurl=/bienvenida.xhtml ; url redirect if you try go to login.xhtml
[urls]
/=onlynot   ; this is if you <welcome-file> on web.xml is the login page. 
/login.xhtml=onlynot
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do when an authorized user hits your login page.
If you just want to redirect them back to some landing page

You could just programmatically check if the current user is authenticated: https://shiro.apache.org/subject.html#the-currently-executing-subject

Comment: I use beans , (I dont have get methot of the page) , I use xhtml with java faces. How to redirect when charge the page (?)